# Mario.c do CS50: Minha pirâmide está invertida

Tags: c

Estou fazendo o curso CS50 e lá precisamos fazer um código que imprime uma pirâmide ao estilo Super Mario Bros. Eu consegui fazer, mas ela está invertida;
Meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int tamanho = 0;
do{
    printf("Tamanho: ");
    scanf("%d", &tamanho);
}
while(tamanho > 8);
for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < tamanho - i; j++){
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

A saída:

[Saída do código](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGn7R.png)

Alguém pode me dizer o que está errado?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Você poderia explicitar como deveria ser a saída.
Se a saida que você quer, for algo assim

```
# 
## 
### 
####
#####
######
#######
########
```

então você pode usar esse algoritmo

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   int tamanho = 0;
   do{
       printf("Tamanho: ");
       scanf("%d", &tamanho);
   }
   while(tamanho > 8);
   for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
       for(int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++){ // MUDANÇAS AQUI
           printf("#");
       }
       printf("\n");
   }
   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: https://replit.com/@Joao-PedroPe529/VagueKnownEngineers#main.c

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int tamanho = 0;
do{
    printf("Tamanho: ");
    scanf("%d", &tamanho);
}
while(tamanho <1||tamanho> 8);
for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < tamanho ; j++){
   if(i+j<tamanho-1)

   printf(" ");
  else
 printf("#");
}
printf("\n");
}
  return 0;
}
```